# Python Pandas: Convert ".value_counts" output to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I want to get the counts of unique values of the dataframe. count_values implements this however I want to use its output somewhere else. How can I convert .count_values output to a pandas dataframe. here is an example code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]})
value_counts = df['a'].value_counts(dropna=True, sort=True)
print(value_counts)
print(type(value_counts))
```

output is:

```
2    3
1    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

What I need is a dataframe like this:

```
unique_values  counts
2              3
1              2
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for name of column from index and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.value_counts().rename_axis('unique_values').reset_index(name='counts')
print (df)
   unique_values  counts
0              2       3
1              1       2
```

Or if need one column DataFrame use [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = df.value_counts().rename_axis('unique_values').to_frame('counts')
print (df)
               counts
unique_values        
2                   3
1                   2
```

Comment: For anyone who wants to have `unique_values` as it's own column (and not the index), simply append `.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)` to the first `df = ...`  expression above.

Comment: Does not work when `value_counts` is passed a list of columns

Answer (score 42):

I just run into the same problem, so I provide my thoughts here.

## Warning

When you deal with the data structure of `Pandas`, you have to aware of the **return type**.

## Another solution here

Like @jezrael mentioned before, `Pandas` do provide API `pd.Series.to_frame`.

#### Step 1

You can also wrap the `pd.Series` to `pd.DataFrame` by just doing

```
df_val_counts = pd.DataFrame(value_counts) # wrap pd.Series to pd.DataFrame
```

Then, you have a `pd.DataFrame` with column name `'a'`, and your first column become the index

```
Input:  print(df_value_counts.index.values)
Output: [2 1]

Input:  print(df_value_counts.columns)
Output: Index(['a'], dtype='object')
```

#### Step 2

What now?

If you want to add new column names here, as a `pd.DataFrame`, you can simply reset the index by the API of [reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

And then, change the column name by a list by API [df.coloumns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html)

```
df_value_counts = df_value_counts.reset_index()
df_value_counts.columns = ['unique_values', 'counts']
```

Then, you got what you need

```
Output:

       unique_values    counts
    0              2         3
    1              1         2
```

#### Full Answer here

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]})
value_counts = df['a'].value_counts(dropna=True, sort=True)

# solution here
df_val_counts = pd.DataFrame(value_counts)
df_value_counts_reset = df_val_counts.reset_index()
df_value_counts_reset.columns = ['unique_values', 'counts'] # change column names
```

Comment: side note: dropna parameter was introduced July, 2021

Answer (score 8):

I'll throw in my hat as well, essentially the same as @wy-hsu solution, but in function format:

```py
def value_counts_df(df, col):
    """
    Returns pd.value_counts() as a DataFrame

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : Pandas Dataframe
        Dataframe on which to run value_counts(), must have column `col`.
    col : str
        Name of column in `df` for which to generate counts

    Returns
    -------
    Pandas Dataframe
        Returned dataframe will have a single column named "count" which contains the count_values()
        for each unique value of df[col]. The index name of this dataframe is `col`.

    Example
    -------
    >>> value_counts_df(pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]}), 'a')
       count
    a
    2      3
    1      2
    """
    df = pd.DataFrame(df[col].value_counts())
    df.index.name = col
    df.columns = ['count']
    return df
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
pd.DataFrame(
    df.groupby(['groupby_col'])['column_to_perform_value_count'].value_counts()
).rename(
    columns={'old_column_name': 'new_column_name'}
).reset_index()
```

Comment: Consider adding more context/information to your code. It also look similar to other solution, though more condensed.

Answer (score 0):

Example of selecting a subset of columns from a dataframe, grouping,  applying `value_count` per group, name `value_count` column as `Count`, and displaying first n groups.

```
# Select 5 columns (A..E) from a dataframe (data_df).
# Sort on A,B. groupby B. Display first 3 groups.
df = data_df[['A','B','C','D','E']].sort_values(['A','B'])
g = df.groupby(['B'])
for n,(k,gg) in enumerate(list(g)[:3]): # display first 3 groups
    display(k,gg.value_counts().to_frame('Count').reset_index())
```