# Streamlit - Applying value_counts / groupby to column selected on run time

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, streamlit

I am trying to apply value_counts method to a Dataframe based on the columns selected dynamically in the Streamlit app

This is what I am trying to do:

```
if st.checkbox("Select Columns To Show"):
    all_columns = df.columns.tolist()
    selected_columns = st.multiselect("Select", all_columns)
    new_df = df[selected_columns]
    st.dataframe(new_df)
```

The above lets me select columns and displays data for the selected columns. I am trying to see how could I apply `value_counts`/`groupby` method on this output in Streamlit app

If I try to do the below

```
st.table(new_df.value_counts())
```

I get the below error

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue lies in passing a list of columns to a dataframe. When you pass a single column in `[]` to a dataframe, you get back a `pandas.Series` object (which has the `value_counts` method). But when you pass a list of columns, you get back a `pandas.DataFrame` (which doesn't have `value_counts` method defined on it).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `st.table(new_df[col_name].value_counts())`

I think the error is because value_counts() is applicable on a Series and not dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Converting [".value_counts" output to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55617313/14045537)

If you want to apply on one single column

```
def value_counts_df(df, col):
    """
    Returns pd.value_counts() as a DataFrame

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : Pandas Dataframe
        Dataframe on which to run value_counts(), must have column `col`.
    col : str
        Name of column in `df` for which to generate counts

    Returns
    -------
    Pandas Dataframe
        Returned dataframe will have a single column named "count" which contains the count_values()
        for each unique value of df[col]. The index name of this dataframe is `col`.

    Example
    -------
    >>> value_counts_df(pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]}), 'a')
       count
    a
    2      3
    1      2
    """
    df = pd.DataFrame(df[col].value_counts())
    df.index.name = col
    df.columns = ['count']
    return df
```

```
val_count_single = value_counts_df(new_df, selected_col)
```

If you want to apply for [all object columns in the dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65841049/14045537)

```
def valueCountDF(df, object_cols):

    c = df[object_cols].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(dropna=False)).T.stack().astype(int)

    p = (df[object_cols].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True,
                                                       dropna=False)).T.stack() * 100).round(2)

    cp = pd.concat([c,p], axis=1, keys=["Count", "Percentage %"])
    return cp
```

```
val_count_df_cols = valueCountDF(df, selected_columns)
```

And Finally, you can use `st.table` or `st.dataframe` to show the dataframe in your streamlit app