# Is there a python function to color/style multi-index levels?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization, pandas-styles

I have defined a function to get **`value_counts`** for each column with **`Count`**, **`Percentage %`** as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

from IPython.display import display


df = sns.load_dataset("diamonds")

def valueCountDF(df):
    
    object_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(exclude=np.number).columns)
    numeric_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns)

    c = df[object_cols].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(dropna=False)).T.stack().astype(int)

    p = (df[object_cols].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True,
                                                       dropna=False)).T.stack() * 100).round(2)

    cp = pd.concat([c,p], axis=1, keys=["Count", "Percentage %"])
    display(cp)

valueCountDF(df)
```

This code outputs:

```
                   Count  Percentage %
cut     Fair        1610          2.98
        Good        4906          9.10
        Ideal      21551         39.95
        Premium    13791         25.57
        Very Good  12082         22.40
color   D           6775         12.56
        E           9797         18.16
        F           9542         17.69
        G          11292         20.93
        H           8304         15.39
        I           5422         10.05
        J           2808          5.21
clarity I1           741          1.37
        IF          1790          3.32
        SI1        13065         24.22
        SI2         9194         17.04
        VS1         8171         15.15
        VS2        12258         22.73
        VVS1        3655          6.78
        VVS2        5066          9.39
```

It is hard for large datasets in `Jupyter Notebooks` with a white background to understand the above data.

So I want to try the [pandas dataframe styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) to style dataframe with the background color for each row index.

```
# Uses the full color range
display(cp.style.background_gradient(cmap='viridis'))
```

[image]

The above one gives **background_gradient** for the df excluding index. I need to color for each row index `(cut, color, clarity)` and their groups.

Precisely, I want to differentiate with **colors** like cut and cut group in one color, color, and color group in one color. Is there a way to do this?

## Update:

**Thanks to [@r-beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13107804/r-beginners)**

Using the below `css` styler

```
table_css = [
    {
        "selector":"th.row_heading.level0",
        "props":[
            ("background-color", "darkseagreen"),
            ("color", "white")
        ]
    }
]
```

```
def valueCountDF(df):
    
    object_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(exclude=np.number).columns)
    numeric_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns)

    c = df[object_cols].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(dropna=False)).T.stack().astype(int)

    p = (df[object_cols].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True,
                                                   dropna=False)).T.stack() * 100).round(2)

    cp = pd.concat([c,p], axis=1, keys=["Count", "Percentage %"])
    #cp.index.names = ['C3','grade']
    #print(cp.style.render())
    style = cp.style.background_gradient(cmap='viridis')
    style = style.set_table_styles(table_css)
    return style

valueCountDF(df)
```

*Able to color the level0 index with only one color as below.*

[image]

Comment: Background gradients are for numbers and cannot be handled by strings. I was able to add a color to the background of the index, as you asked. I'm not very good with HTML, so this is my limit. I've given the code to Colab for reference.

Comment: @r-beginners, this is what I need, but want to differentiate with colors like `cut` and cut group in one color, color and color group in one color.....

Comment: Is that possible??

Comment: Creating a style sheet for each of the 3Cs didn't work, nor did creating settings for the 3Cs in one style sheet. This may be due to my lack of html knowledge.

Comment: If you don't mind using my code, why don't you update your question?

Comment: Hopefully you will get the answers you want. Comments with links to collaborations will be deleted.

Comment: Please try to run this code to understand the class name set in css. `print(cp.style.render())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Load Data**

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import colors

df = sns.load_dataset("diamonds")
```

**Reset the index and rename axis**.Update the code in the function  `valueCountDF`

```
def valueCountDF(df):
    
    object_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(exclude=np.number).columns)
    numeric_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns)

    c = df[object_cols].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(dropna=False)).T.stack().astype(int)

    p = (df[object_cols].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True,
                                                       dropna=False)).T.stack() * 100).round(2)

    cp = pd.concat([c,p], axis=1, keys=["Count", "Percentage %"])

    # Reset index and name the axis
    cp = cp.rename_axis(['Variable','Class']).reset_index()
    cp['Variable'] = np.where(cp['Variable'].duplicated(),'',cp['Variable'])

    return cp
```

Using `np.broadcast_to` and `radd()`

```
def colr(x):
    y = x.assign(k=x['Variable'].ne("").cumsum())
    d = dict(enumerate(colors.cnames))
    y[:] = np.broadcast_to(y['k'].map(d).radd('background-color:').to_numpy()[:,None]
                          ,y.shape)
    return y.drop("k",1)
```

**Apply the style**

```
val_count = valueCountDF(df)
val_count.style.apply(colr,axis=None).format({'Percentage %': '{:.1f}'})
```

[image]