# How to generate the component id in the Networkx graph?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, networkx

I have a large Graph Network generated using `Networkx` package.

[image]

Here I'm adding a sample

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

G = nx.path_graph(4)
nx.add_path(G, [10, 11, 12])
```

I'm trying to create a `dataframe` with Node, degrees, component id, component.

Created degrees using

```
degrees = list(nx.degree(G))

data = pd.DataFrame([list(d) for d in degrees], columns=['Node', 'degree']).sort_values('degree', ascending=False)
```

extracted components using

```
Gcc = sorted(nx.connected_components(G), key=len, reverse=True)

Gcc
```

```
[{0, 1, 2, 3}, {10, 11, 12}]
```

And not sure how I can create the `Component ID` and `components` in the data.

Required output:

```
  Node  degree  ComponentID  Components
1   1   2           1         {0, 1, 2, 3}
2   2   2           1         {0, 1, 2, 3}
5   11  2           2         {10, 11, 12}
0   0   1           1         {0, 1, 2, 3}
3   3   1           1         {0, 1, 2, 3}
4   10  1           2         {10, 11, 12}
6   12  1           2         {10, 11, 12}
```

How to generate the component ids and add them to the nodes and degrees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create triplets of `Node`, `ComponentId` and `Component` by enumerating over the connected component list, then create a new dataframe from these triplets and `merge` it with the given dataframe on `Node`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(n, i, c) for i,c in enumerate(Gcc, 1) for n in c], 
                        columns=['Node', 'ComponentID', 'Components'])

data = data.merge(df, on='Node')
```

Alternatively you can use `map` instead of `merge` to individually create `ComponentID` and `Components` columns

```
d = dict(enumerate(Gcc, 1))
data['ComponentID'] = data['Node'].map({n:i for i,c in d.items() for n in c})
data['Components']  = data['ComponentID'].map(d)
```

---

```
print(data)

   Node  degree  ComponentID    Components
1     1       2            1  {0, 1, 2, 3}
2     2       2            1  {0, 1, 2, 3}
5    11       2            2  {10, 11, 12}
0     0       1            1  {0, 1, 2, 3}
3     3       1            1  {0, 1, 2, 3}
4    10       1            2  {10, 11, 12}
6    12       1            2  {10, 11, 12}
```

Comment: Just in case if you are interested in more questions. Plz check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/65841049/14045537, https://stackoverflow.com/q/63481466/14045537

Comment: @Pluviophile i'll check that.