# Plot the count of a Pandas df column using Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a df column where its data are only categorical (e.g., [a, b, c, a, a, d, c, b, etc]).
I want to plot the count of these data using plotly count bar (bar chart).

I have calculated the count of the data using `df.groupby('<col_name>')['<col_name>'].count()`, but this returns a series data structure so I will only have the count data (1-D).

How can I get the count result and the corresponding data item in the resulting output efficiently?

I want to get this output and plot the bar chart using Plotly:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.bar(count_df, x="<col_name>", y="count", color="count", title="----------")
fig.show()
```

Comment: I think you need [this](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#bar-chart-with-long-format-data).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't get more efficient than this:

```
df['x'].plot(kind = 'hist')
```

[image]

And NO, this isn't matplotlib, but rather a figure constructed directly from a pandas dataframe using plotly as a backend. And yes, it's awesome!

#### Complete code:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
random.seed(7)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[random.choice(list('abcde')) for i in range(25)]})
fig = df['x'].plot(kind = 'hist')
fig.layout.bargap = 0
fig.show()
```

Comment: While this is efficient, the x-axis values for a histogram need to be *at least* ordered, if not numeric. Also, the y-axis values need to be continuous. Here, the x-axis is categorical and the y-axis is discrete. So we need a bar or column chart, not a histogram.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question.

I found a solution by converting the result of value_counts(returns a Series) to a pd DataFrame. Ref : [SO question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47136484/9213600)

```
import plotly.express as px

new_df = df['<col_name>'].value_counts().rename_axis('<col_name>').reset_index(name='counts')

fig = px.bar(new_df, x="<col_name>", y="counts", color="counts", title="----------")
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to use .index of the result to give you the values for x-axis and the series itself for the y-axis.

Also, I think using df[‘col_name’].value_counts() is probably what you want to use here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it easily by using `hist()`, for example:

```
df['<col_name>'].hist()
```

and also you can see the abs frequency.

Another way to do the same is:

```
df['<col_name>'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: Thank you but I want to use Plotly and not the Pandas builtin stuff